# Find and Hide View from View Hierarchy

Tags: swift

I have a given view hierarchy as follows:

```
View F
  > View C
    > View D
      > View A
      > View P
    > View B
```

How could I able to hide View C?

I have came up with the following logic. However, I wonder whether or not it is right way of doing it?

```
func givenViews (view1 : UIView , view2: UIView)
{
    aViews = [UIView]()
    bViews = [UIView]()

   var aView = view1
   var bView = view2


   // first put all superviews into array
   while aView.superview != nil
   {
    aViews.append(aView)
    aView = aView.superview
   }

   while bView.superview != nil
   {
    bViews.append(bView)
    bView = bView.superview
   }

   // find the first common view which is C and hide it
   for a in aViews
   {
     for b in bViews
     {
       if a == b
       {
        a.hidden = true
        break 
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: It would be a lot simpler to have an outlet directly to view C, wouldn't it?

Comment: @matt, there is no information given regarding to C. I approach the problem as follows it is obvious that C is the first common(parent) View for A and B in the view hierarchy.

Comment: That makes no sense to me; you always know what views you've got, because you put them there. At the very least you can give a view a `tag` and now you can always access it with a single call.

Comment: I understand @matt, but that was an interview question and I have posted my answer and interviewer has told me that there is a better way of doing it. That is why I want to know what is the better approach for this solution. If there is a tag, it is easy, but there is no tag id.

Comment: Well it seems a stupid question. It's a complete unrealistic situation.

Comment: @matt, check that question, it is being asked several times.. https://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/How-to-detect-a-common-superview-QTN_1615605.htm

Comment: How do you think that *"How to detect a common superview."* is the same question as your's? You are asking how to hide a view. One might even say you are walking *down* the view hierarchy. The FB question is asking about looking up.

Comment: @dfd, actually question is pretty much same, is not it? First I need to find the common view then hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to hide the first common ancestor if I understand your code correctly.

If so, then you can use `isDescendant(of:)` like so:

```
func givenViews(view1: UIView, view2: UIView) -> UIView? {
    if view2.isDescendant(of: view1) { return view1 }

    var aView: UIView? = view1
    while let testView = aView, !view2.isDescendant(of: testView) {
        aView = testView.superview
    }

    return aView
}
```

Comment: @kovpas, what if `view2` is a descendant of `view 1`? and also there is no `return`, it is `void()`, how do you hide the first common view?